# Redirect https://subdomain.example.com to https://example.com/some-web-page in IIS

Tags: iis, https, web-config, ssl-certificate

I have a subdomain (subdomain.example.com) that I want to redirect it to this Url format on my website https://example.com/some-web-page.

I created an empty site in IIS, the site only contains a web.config file with this rule:

```
<rule name="subdomain.example.com Redirect" stopProcessing="false">
 <match url="^\/?$" />
 <conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*subdomain\.example\.com.*" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://example.com/some-web-page/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Now, subdomain.example.com is redirecting as it should but https://subdomain.example.com is taking me to https://example.com home page and the address bar shows an error saying "The identity of the website has not been verified.  Server's certificate does not match the Url."

I should also mention that I have purchased an additional certificate for https://subdomain.example.com.

How can I make this https redirect to work in such scenario?

Comment: Do you have an SSL installed? If so, is it just for the domain or is it a wildcard SSL?

Comment: I do have an SSL installed.. I think the problem is because the server has a single IP address and that cannot be shared between two SSL certs.  I just asked the hosting company to add a new public IP address.  Hopefully pointing the subdomain DNS to the newly created IP address is going to fix the problem.